# JPA Hibernate HSQLDB - VARBINARY() field and error attempting to select

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hsqldb

I found a similar question at [HSQLDB: Duplicate column name, unsupported internal operation: Type, invalid character for cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323681), but there was no intelligible answer. I also looked at http://old.nabble.com/unsupported-internal-operation%3A-StatementDMQL-td27427172.html which reports the issue is a bug in HSQLDB, but it should be fixed in the version I am using (2.2). So, here's the details of the problem:

I have an entity which stores some byte[] data in a VARBINARY(128) field inside of HSQLDB. The table is created successfully, but when I try to select from the table, I get the following stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Type java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Type
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.Util.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:802)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2533)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2276)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2271)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1268)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:274)
    at com.dns.recursive.ipcache.data.CacheWrapper.findEntry(CacheWrapper.java:206)
    at com.dns.recursive.ipcache.net.TCPWorker.run(TCPWorker.java:114)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Type
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.result.Result.newErrorResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementDMQL.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: unsupported internal operation: Type
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.runtimeError(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.types.Type.subtract(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ExpressionArithmetic.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ExpressionOrderBy.getValue(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.buildResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getSingleResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.QuerySpecification.getResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementQuery.getResult(Unknown Source)
    ... 24 more
```

I could really use some help in figuring out the cause of this. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unsupported internal operation is a generic error which reports the class in which the error occured. It is the low-level line of defence against errors. Usually the SQL error is caught and reported before this type of error occurs. In this case it is not caught. Other exception reports with the same error string may be totally unrelated.

You need to report the CREATE TABLE statement and the SELECT statement which runs against it.

The stack trace indicates there is an ORDER BY clause which includes something like ORDER BY A - B where A or B are not numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It sounds perfectly plausible, but I have already branched my code and worked around the problem in a different way.